# When push same as new element in array, both are referencing to each other,so how to push without referencing with old element in Knockout.js?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

How to push same element observable array without any reference b/w old and new element?

To add multiple category with diff sub-category

[image]

As you can see in above When I am Click on “+” button, new element is pushed in array and after that trying to Change “New” in sub-Category for second row, it;’s auto-changed in first row also.

Comment: Clone the object before adding it. Using `var objToPush = ko.toJS(ko.fromJS(existingObj));`

Comment: Check out the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333915/how-do-i-make-a-deep-copy-of-a-knockout-object-that-was-created-by-the-mapping-p

Comment: Thanks, Above code working fine in case of Parent Items, but in case of it's child items (category), same issue is occurring.

Comment: @haim770 can you help me for same also.

Comment: You probably need to deep-clone. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333915/how-do-i-make-a-deep-copy-of-a-knockout-object-that-was-created-by-the-mapping-p